# Iterate angular key value using angular material design

Tags: javascript, angularjs, material-design, angular-material

I have an Angular 1.x app that is using Angular Material, I am trying to retrieve the key for array item below but this doesn't seem to work when using material design - any ideas what is incorrect with the following code?

```
<div md-virtual-repeat="(key,player) in team.players">
  {{ player.name }}
  {{ key }}
</div>
```

I would like to get the key of the array (will be an integer), however the following doesn't output any value for {{ key }}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[mdVirtualRepeat API Documentation](https://material.angularjs.org/latest/api/directive/mdVirtualRepeat):

> Track by, as alias, and (key, value) syntax are not supported.